# How to get jQuery pop to disappear again?

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup

How do I get my jQuery pop-up to disappear again when "approvals" is clicked again?

```
$(function() {
$('a.approvals').click(function(e) {
    var html = '<div id="info">';
    html +=    '<a href ="http://www.coned.com/es/specs/gas/Section%20VII.pdf" div id="ConED"><img border= "0" src="con_edison_logo.png" /></a>';
    html +=    '<a href ="pdfs/2009_natl_grid_blue_book_web.pdf" div id="NationalGrid"><img border= "0" src="national_grid_logo.png"  /></a>';
    html +=    '<a href ="http://database.ul.com/cgi-bin/XYV/template/LISEXT/1FRAME/showpage.html?name=JIFQ.MH46473&ccnshorttitle=Gas+Boosters&objid=1079858133&cfgid=1073741824&version=versionless&parent_id=1073988683&sequence=1" div id="ULLogo"><img border= "0" src="ul_logo_a.png" /></a>';
    html +=    '<a href ="http://license.reg.state.ma.us/pubLic/pl_products/pb_search.asp?type=G&manufacturer=Etter+Engineering+Company+Inc.&model=&product=&description=&psize=50" div id="MassGov"><img border= "0" src="massgovlogo.png" /></a>';
    html +=    '<div id="ApprovalsTxtpopup">With the exception of the UL-listing, the above approval agencies are region-specific, should your local agencies require any further documentation other than our UL-listing, please contact ETTER Engineering Toll Free 1-800-444-1962 for further assistance.</div>';
    html +=     '</div>';
    $('#Wrapper').append(html).children('#info').hide().fadeIn(400);
}, function() {
    $('#info').remove();
});
```

});

Comment: Could you provide a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) demo? Also, your HTML is wrong, i.e. `<a href='…' div id='ConED'>`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
$('a.approvals').click(function(e) {
    var html = '<div id="info">';
    html +=    '<a href ="http://www.coned.com/es/specs/gas/Section%20VII.pdf" div id="ConED"><img border= "0" src="con_edison_logo.png" /></a>';
    html +=    '<a href ="pdfs/2009_natl_grid_blue_book_web.pdf" div id="NationalGrid"><img border= "0" src="national_grid_logo.png"  /></a>';
    html +=    '<a href ="http://database.ul.com/cgi-bin/XYV/template/LISEXT/1FRAME/showpage.html?name=JIFQ.MH46473&ccnshorttitle=Gas+Boosters&objid=1079858133&cfgid=1073741824&version=versionless&parent_id=1073988683&sequence=1" div id="ULLogo"><img border= "0" src="ul_logo_a.png" /></a>';
    html +=    '<a href ="http://license.reg.state.ma.us/pubLic/pl_products/pb_search.asp?type=G&manufacturer=Etter+Engineering+Company+Inc.&model=&product=&description=&psize=50" div id="MassGov"><img border= "0" src="massgovlogo.png" /></a>';
    html +=    '<div id="ApprovalsTxtpopup">With the exception of the UL-listing, the above approval agencies are region-specific, should your local agencies require any further documentation other than our UL-listing, please contact ETTER Engineering Toll Free 1-800-444-1962 for further assistance.</div>';
    html +=     '</div>';
    $('#Wrapper').append(html).children('#info').hide().fadeIn(400);
}, function() {
    $('#info').remove();
    $('#Wrapper').children('#info').hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `toggle` instead of `click`:

```
$('a.approvals').toggle(function(e) {
    ...same code...
```

[Live test case](http://jsfiddle.net/z2mqE/).